# SQL Server : Alter Schema Transfer in dynamic query not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
declare @q nvarchar(max) = ''

set @q = 'ALTER SCHEMA [targetSchema] TRANSFER [sourceSchema].[tableName]'
exec sp_executesql @q
```

This call hangs forever. Why is not this allowed?

What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine for me. Use `sp_who2` or `sp_whoisactive` to see whats blocking it.

Comment: Why are you using `sp_executesql` at all here? There's nothing "dynamic" about your query. Just execute `ALTER SCHEMA [targetSchema] TRANSFER [sourceSchema].[tableName];`

Comment: It might be an obvious one, but do you have permissions to run stored procedures and alter schemas?